# $Z(y^2-x^3) \subset \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Prove that the algebraic variety $Z(y^2-x^3) = \{(x, y)\in\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^2\,\,|\,\,y^2-x^3=0\}$ is not isomorphic to the affine space $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^1$.

[i.e., there are no polynomials $p_1, p_2 \in\mathbb{R}[x], q\in\mathbb{R}[x, y]$ such that $(p_1(x), p_2(x))\in Z(y^2-x^3) \,\,\forall x\in\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^1$ and $q(x, y)\in\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^1\,\,\forall (x, y)\in Z(y^2-x^3)$]

I find this result more or less intuitive, but I'm having a hard time trying to formalize it.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You can compute the dimension of the Zariski tangent space at the origin, which is $2$. This reflects the fact that this curve is singular there.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976489

Answer (score 3):

One can show that the ring of coordinates of $(y^2-x^3)$ is $\Bbb R[t^2,t^3]$, and that of the line is, of course, $\Bbb R[t]$. You're reduced to show these are not isomorphic algebras. One way to show these are not isomorphic is to note the former is not a unique factorization domain, for example.

Comment: I'm confident this works out when the base field is algebraically closed (like $\mathbb C$), but I'm wondering this is okay for $\mathbb R$. I guess one would need to check the equivalence of categories of fg $k$-algebra domains and affine $k$-varieties is okay for all $k$.

Comment: @hwong557 In this case you can tensor with $\Bbb C$ and everything's fine. But you don't need that, however. The fact the category of affine varieties is opposite to the category of algebras is true always. The bijection makes no use of any extra properties of the field.

Comment: Okay great thanks!