# $x^2, x^3$ being irreducible in $F[x^2, x^3]$

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, integral-domain

(For $F$ field) $F[x^2,x^3]$$\;$clearly $x^2$ is irreducible as$\;$ $x^2=x\cdot x$$\;$ but $x\not\in F[x^2,x^3]$.

Can the same be applied to $x^3?$$\;$ $x^3=x^2\cdot x$$\;$  (Neither of which are units.)

If I am totally incorrect, how do I show that $x^2,x^3$ are irreducible in $F[x^2, x^3]$,

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should remove the UFD tag, since you're trying to prove it is not a UFD.

Comment: Looks ok to me. Your ring is a subring of the Euclidean domain $F[x]$, so any factorization in your ring is also a factorization in the more familiar ring (but, as you observed, not the other way round)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definition of irreducible element in any ring $R$ is as follows: $p$ is irreducible in $R$ if $$p=ab \implies a\in R^\times\ \text{or}\ b\in R^\times;\quad a,b\in R$$

You are free to think of irreducible elements as those that have exactly two divisors (up to multiplication by unit) - $1$ and themselves.
That means that if you want to prove that $x^2$ is irreducible in $F[x^2,x^3]$, you need to show that it is impossible to write $x^2 = p(x)q(x)$ in $F[x^2,x^3]$, unless $p(x)$ or $q(x)$ is unit.

If you write $x^2 = x\cdot x$, this is not factorization in $F[x^2,x^3]$, so this tells you nothing of irreducibility in $F[x^2,x^3]$ (at least not directly). In contrast, it is factorization in $F[x]$ and is unique factorization into irreducibles in UFD $F[x]$.

You can proceed by assuming that $x^2 = p(x)q(x)$, where $p(x),q(x)\in F[x^2,x^3]$ and assume that neither is unit. But that means that $\deg p, \deg q \geq 1$, which implies $\deg p = \deg q = 1$, since $\deg p + \deg q = 2$. But, this is contradiction, since there are no polynomials of degree $1$ in $F[x^2,x^3]$. Similarly for $x^3$.

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on unique prime factorization in $F[x]$.

Your factorization $x^3 = x^2 \cdot x$ is of course irrelevant because $x \notin F[x^2,x^3]$. It's like saying $3 = 9\cdot\frac13$ and calling that a factorization in $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Q$.

Comment: I don't even really understand the concept of $x^2$ being irreducible, my textbook says $x^2$ is irreducible if $x^2=q(x)p(x)$ and with $p(x)$ or $q(x)$ is a unit.  But clearly $x$ is not a unit?

Answer (score 0):

Your best friend is the degree. $\deg(fg)=\deg(f)+\deg(g)$.

Comment: $deg(x^6)=deg((x^3)^2)$?

Comment: First show that all the degree $0$ elements are units. If $x^2$ was not irreducible $x^2=fg$ and then take degrees. Does your ring have any degree $1$ elements?

Comment: As all constants are elements of the F, then clearly they are all units.  Also, $2=deg(x^2)=deg(f)+deg(g)$ 

Case 1: $deg(f)=2$ and  $deg(g)=0$ Then $g$ would then be a unit, $x^2$ irreducibe.

Case 2: $deg(f)=1$ and $deg(g)=1$, contradiction as there are no linear polynomials in the ring.

Thanks for the help!